# Stargazer and GAMM models

Tags: r, stargazer, gam

I've run a series of generalized additive mixed models (GAMMs) using the gamm function from the mgcv package and I'm trying to organize all of my models side by side in a publication ready table using stargazer.  However, I'm unsuccessful with outputing with just one model.  So for my first model, my code is like this:

`model1 <- gamm(y ~ s(time, bs="ps", k=15, m=2), data=data, random=list(student_id=~1 + time)) summary(model1[[1]]) summary(model1[[2]])`

To output the results, which should include the fixed, and random effects, significance of smooth terms, adjusted R squared, as well as AIC, BIC, and logLik, I tried the following:

`stargazer(model1$gam, summary=TRUE, type="html", out="output.doc")`.

Unfortunately, I got the following error:

```
"% Error: Unrecognized object type."
```

I also followed someone's response to the post titled "stargazer and gam how to include the whole summary output" on stackoverflow.com by doing this:

`require (memisc) toLatex(summary(model1$gam)$s.table)`

and I obtained the following error:

```
"Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'"
```

I'm sure it's apparent from my question that I do not know what I'm doing.  I've searched the internet pretty thoroughly and I am unable to apply what I've seen to my own problem.  I'm very new to R and in the past, I've used stargazer to output descriptives and htmlreg to output hlm models using lmer function to tables, but this is the first time when I am using stargazer to organize my gamm models.

So my main objective is to output the results from my multiple GAMM models and place them side-by-side in a large publication-ready table.

I'd appreciate any assistance you can provide me.  Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Have you tried `stargazer(summary(model1$gam)$s.table, etc)`?

Comment: I just tried it. Thank you.  The output only gives me the smoothing effect of time, its edf, Ref.df, F, and p value.  It does not give me the rest of the output that I was hoping to achieve, such as fixed effects, random effects, along with aic, bic, etc. Do you have any more ideas?  Many thanks!